# Flutter: How to generate random boolean value with my own probability?

Tags: flutter

When I use the code :

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextBool();
```

It returns a 50% / 50% probability value (true / false).

How can I generate a true-false value with my own probability like (20% / 35% / 70% ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example the result is 30% likely to be false, 70% likely to be true.

```
Random r = new Random();
double falseProbability = .3;
bool booleanResult = r.nextDouble() > falseProbability;
```

Comment: Thanks, So for this example booleanResult is 70% true.

Answer (score 4):

Simpler example:

```
Random r = new Random();
bool result = r.nextDouble() <= 0.7;
```

Gives a chance of 70% to get True result.